# How can I "compare" two lists in Python?

Tags: python, loops

the first list:

```
words_length_list = [word for word in temp if len(word) == current_word_length]
```

first list output: **['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten']**

the second list:

```
current_word_truncated_list = list(current_word_truncated)
```

second list output: **['i','e']**

I want all words from the first list which contains the letters "e" and "i" (from the second list).

The output should be:

```
result: ['five','eight','nine']
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2):

I understood your question, but it is poorly written.
Here is my solution:

```
array1=["Anna","Zeynal","Nicole","Carl"] #The words that you want to check for letters

array2=['e','f'] #The letters that you want to check for in words above

for member in array1:
    for letter in array2:
        if letter in member:
         print(member)
```

Running it gives:

```
Zeynal
Nicole

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am new to Python, came from Java, but as you can see the solution is very simple.

Comment: Later on you can easily modify it to store the names in some third list. I hope I was of help!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can do it with list comprehension:

```
lst = ['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten']

new_lst = [word for word in lst if 'e' in word and 'i' in word]

print(new_lst)
# output: ['five', 'eight', 'nine']
```